# Symfony не могу получить entity для relation поля в фикстуре

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine2

Не могу вытащить данные в `entity` из фикстуры.

**Суть:**

> Есть `Entity/Player`, у которой есть `relation ManyToOne` к
> `Entity/PlayerTypes`. Данные для `PlayerTypes` уже заведены в таблице.
> Когда создается `Player`, нужно указать `PlayerType`, сеттер типа
> игрока у `Entity/Player` принимает на вход `Entity/PlayerTypes`.

Собственно, если бы я пользовался голым SQL, я бы просто вставил в запросе ID в виде цифры. Но доктрина сгенерировала мне сеттер который требует целую `entity` связанного класса на вход - как я понимаю такая философия *orm*, а потому решил вытаскивать его прямо в фикстуре в методе `load()`. И тут то все и заверте... `ObjectManager` упорно отказывается видеть данные в таблице, хотя в контроллере `$playerType = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(PlayerTypes::class)->find(1);` - все видит и оттуда игрок корректно создается.

Пробовал разные методы помимо `find()`, вплоть до написания собственного в репозитории - итог тот же. В контроллере все ОК, в фикстуре - ничего не находит.
Подозреваю, что дело в `ObjectManager`, но в чем конкретно - пока не могу сообразить. `$playerType = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(PlayerTypes::class);` - класс репозитория при этом возвращает.

Подскажите пожалуйста, куда копать и правильно ли вообще я работаю с фикстурами)?

**Фикстура**

```
use App\Entity\Players;
use App\Entity\PlayerTypes;
use Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Fixture;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ObjectManager;

class AppFixtures extends Fixture
{
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        //всегда возвращает null, ходя данные с id = 1 точно есть
        $playerType = $manager->getRepository(PlayerTypes::class)->find(1);

        $player = new Players();
        $player->setLogin('test');
        $player->setFidPlayertype($playerType);

        $manager->persist($player);
        $manager->flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: По умолчанию запуск фикстур очищает БД. Возможно, на момент создания у вас уже нет искомой записи.

Comment: Да, так и есть. Спасибо, помогли навести на нужную мысль)

Answer (score 0):

Про правильность работы с фикстурами вы задались хорошим вопросом. Вкратце - вы не правильно работаете с фикстурами.

Для реализации связи между сущностями вам нужно использовать `reference`

Вот где это описано в документации

https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html#sharing-objects-between-fixtures

Comment: Не совсем мой случай. Как я понял референсы работают только тогда, когда мы вставляем новые связанные данные. У меня же - уже есть фиксированные данные в таблице, которые мне нужно использовать. Но бандл фикстур очищает все данные перед загрузкой как уже упоминал @Dmitry Kozlov. Мне просто нужно было понять как их сохранить, но с этим я разобрался, отпишу ответом на собственный вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. Бандл фикстур действительно очищает все данные перед загрузкой фикстуры как уже упоминал @Dmitry Kozlov, поэтому при запуске фикстуры в консоли, нужно указать название таблиц, которые не нужно очищать. В моем случае, всего то нужно было запускать фикстуру вот такой командой:

```
symfony console doctrine:fixtures:load --purge-exclusions=player_types
```

Comment: Также можно использовать параметр --append. Очистки не будет и если параметры кардинально не менялись, то вполне действенно. "By default the load command purges the database, removing all data from every table. To append your fixtures’ data add the --append option." Еще опция --group=PlayerTypes обновит только один тип фикстур